# How can I override FrontController in prestashop 1.5?

Tags: controller, overriding, prestashop, front-controller

I know there are similar questions, but none of them can solve my problem.

I placed a FrontController.php file in /override/classes/controller/

It contains this code:

```
Class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore{
    public function displayHeader(){
        if(!self::$initialized) $this->init();

        $this->context->smarty->assign('test_ok','okok');

        return parent::displayHeader();       
    } 
}//end FrontController
```

From my custom theme, in header.tpl I placed a test code like this

```
{$test_ok}
```

And get this:

Notice: Undefined index: test_ok in [...]/cache/smarty/compile/81/a3/76/81a3760f9c0cb8c9ff677a0e7b59d8962cdaaeda.file.header.tpl.php on line 147

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in [...]/cache/smarty/compile/81/a3/76/81a3760f9c0cb8c9ff677a0e7b59d8962cdaaeda.file.header.tpl.php on line 147

---

I also tried to assign that smarty var directly in FrontControllerCore.php (only just to test) but got the same notice.

---

Any idea?

Comment: UPDATE: I succeeded in get the ovverride recognized, meaning that now I can read this in class_index:

  'FrontController' => 'override/classes/controller/FrontController.php',
  'FrontControllerCore' => 'classes/controller/FrontController.php',

---

That said, I still get the same error when I try to recall a smarty variable in header.tpl

Hope someone can help me..

Comment: NEW UPDATE: I can see the smarty variable IF I assign it in initHeader() INSTEAD of displayHeader() or init().

Why can't I use that 2 methods? Isn't quite strange? Can someone explain the mechanics of this behaviour?

Comment: LAST UPDATE: the reason I have to use initHeader instead of displayHeader probably is that displayHeader is deprecated.
Using initHeader or initContent is safe.

Answer (score 3):

When you create an override you need to recreate the class index.

To do so just remove the file `/cache/class_index.php` then recreate it (be sure to `chmod` it to `666` so Prestashop can write it (you can also just remove the content of the file of course).

Comment: Hi, thank you but it doesn't work. I already tried (and again now).

It's really strange to me. Even if I mode directly the core file, empty class_index and all the smarty cache, it doesn't see changes, seems...

I instead succesfully created three modules.

So... Don't know..

Answer (score 1):

Function **displayHeader()** **is not called** in Prestashop 1.5 and later versions because it is marked as deprecated. So when you override a not calling function nothing could be happened and you get no results on output.

As I see here the **answer from user1145716** is more helpful for your situation and you can override **initHeader()** function to see results on output.

Answer (score 0):

be carefull ! in PS1.5 method displayHeader() was deprecated so you have to use initHeader() then it will work, i had same problem.